# Greedy TV Watching Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, greedy

I am trying to implement the following greedy algorithm in C:

Alex is a great fan of television. He wrote down all the TV programs he is interested in for
today. His list contains n shows, i-th of them starts at moment li and ends at moment ri.
Alex owns two TVs. He can watch two different shows simultaneously with two TVs but he can only
watch one show at any given moment on a single TV. If one show ends at the same moment some
other show starts then you can't watch them on a single TV.
Alex wants to check out all n shows. Are two TVs enough to do so? Write a program to help Alex
figure out the answer.
Input
The first line contains one integer which indicate the number of shows.
Each of the next n lines contains two integers starting and ending time of i-th show.
Output
If Alex is able to check out all the shows using only two TVs then print "YES" (without quotes).
Otherwise, print "NO" (without quotes).

Example input
3
1, 2
2, 3
4, 5
output
YES

However, whenever I run my implementation, I recieve a segmentation fault error. I'm sure it is something I am not seeing but I cannot seem to narrow down the issues. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    const int num;

    int A[num][2]; //should be declared after fscanf

FILE* filePtr = fopen("input2.txt","r");

fscanf(filePtr, "%d\n", &num);

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        fscanf(filePtr, "%d, %d\n", &A[i][0], &A[i][1]);
    }

    fclose(filePtr);

    int temp[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < (num - i) - 1; j++){
            if(A[j][0] > A[j+1][0]){
                temp[0] = A[j][0];
                temp[1] = A[j][1];
                A[j][0] = A[j+1][0];
                A[j][1] = A[j+1][1];
                A[j+1][0] = A[j+1][0];
                A[j+1][1] = A[j+1][1];
            }
        }

    }

    int TV1 = 0, TV2 = 0;
    int currentShow = 0;

    for(int i = A[0][0]; i <= A[num-1][0] && currentShow < num; i++){
        if(i == A[currentShow][0]){
            if(TV1 == 0) TV1 = A[currentShow][1] - A[currentShow][0];
            else if(TV2 == 0) TV2 = A[currentShow][1] - A[currentShow][0];
            else{
                printf("No.\n");
                break;
            }
            currentShow++;
        }

        if(TV1 > 0) TV1--;
        if(TV2 > 0) TV2--;
    }

    if(currentShow == num) printf("Yes.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: " If one show ends at the same moment some other show starts then you can't watch them on a single TV" - why not?

Comment: @paxdiablo I don't know I did not design the question

Comment: That;s okay, Noah, it just seemed a strange one since my kids are perfectly fine watching hour after endless hour of consecutive dross on a single TV :-) In any case, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const int num;
int A[num][2];
```

This is a rather serious problem, `num` hasn't been set to anything when you create `A`. That's unlikely to end well.

If you want to use `num` as a dimension specifier, you should wait until you know what it is (after the first `fscanf`). Compilers are good but I'm pretty certain they're subject to the same temporal rules as we are :-)

There's also a host of other things jumping out at me, such as:

- not checking the return values of `fopen` or `fscanf`;
- trying to modify `num` even though it's marked `const`.

Fixing those would also go a long way toward solving your problems. You should generally check *any* call that could have a downstream effect later on, such as with:

```
FILE* filePtr = fopen("input2.txt", "r");
if (filePtr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file\n");
    return 1;
}
```

and:

```
if (fscanf(filePtr, "%d, %d\n", &A[i][0], &A[i][1]) != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not get two integers from file\n");
    fclose(filePtr);
    return 1;
}
```

---

And, as an aside, I'm not entirely certain I understand how your algorithm works. It may be worthwhile breaking it down into separate modules so that it's easier to understand and debug.

The approach I would take would be to work out all the timepoints you're interested in which, in your case, is everything from the minimum `1` through the `maximum`5`.

Then, for all of those, count the number of durations in which it appears. If that's more than two then obviously two TVs are not going to do the job.

From a conceptual point of view, your test data would be:

```
Timepoint  Appears-in:  1-2  2-3  4-5  count
---------  --------------------------  -----
    1                   yes  no   no     1
    2                   yes  yes  no     2
    3                   no   yes  no     1
    4                   no   no   yes    1
    5                   no   no   yes    1
```

So that one's okay.

Comment: Thank you so much @paxdiablo! I have edited the code with some of your suggestions but I am still getting a seg fault. Any idea why?

Comment: @Noah, it's not considered good form to edit your question in a way that invalidates answers, it rather defeats the purpose of the Q&A nature of SO. It's okay to *add* detail for clarification so I suggest you do that.

Comment: oops! I was trying to show that I implemented your suggestions. Anyways, even with those in place, I still get a segmentation fault error and don't know why. Does it have to do with my fopen/fclose perhaps? I have never used these before.

Comment: I have finally got it working after implementing your suggestions and checking my file naming! I believe these both helped to fix my issues. Thank you very much!